# Transpose the number of converging features into an attribute of a new generalized feature

Tags: shapefile

I've been doing manually a task that I'm not sure that is possible to automatize: I have a shapefile with several lines, obteined from google maps, where each feature is a path. I would like to obtain e new shapefile with a generalization of those, having in a field the number of cases that would be considered to converge in each feature. The image explains it much better...

[image]

I'm oppened to the following:

1. Digitalize by myself the shapefile that will support the calculation of the field values. The hard part isn't having the shape. The exhausting process is transposing to each segment the number of cases that are considered to converge.
2. Consider a raster approach to the issue.

Comment: I for once am open to you telling us which software you're working with.

Comment: Neither QGIS or ArcGis

Comment: You can't work with two softwares simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry for my english, maybe I didn't understand your question. I meant that I can work with ArcGis or qgis, indistinctly.